# How to find the following summation

Tags: real-analysis, summation

How to find the following sum $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n}{n^3}$$

I have tried by rationalizing. But after that I got stuck.

Comment: May be easier to consider $\sum r^n/n^3$ instead of using this specific value for $r$

Comment: Note also that if you call this sum $s(r)$, then $rs'(r)=\sum r^n/n^2$, and likewise $r(rs'(r))'=\sum r^n/n$ etc. Taking a derivative and multiplying by $r$ will reduce the power of $n$ in the denominator. Continue until you get a geometric sum, which you can write as a closed formula. Then reverse the process by integrating.

Comment: Yes, except that the integrations aren't elementary.

Comment: Almost by definition, the sum evaluates to ${\rm Li}_3\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$, where ${\rm Li}_n(z)$ is a [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). According to WA, this value can be reexpressed in more common constants.
$${\rm Li}_3\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) = \frac{4 \zeta(3)}{5} + \frac{\pi^2}{15} \log\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{12}\log^3\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x<1$,by differentiation,

$$S(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^3}$$

$$xS'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2}$$

$$x(xS'(x))'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$$

$$(x(xS'(x))')'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}=\frac1{1-x}.$$

Then by integration

$$(xS'(x))'=-\frac{\log(1-x)}x$$ and the closed-form stops here.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, for $|r|<1$, 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n/n^3 = \text{polylog}(3,r)$$

This is not an elementary function.